# How to get AD properties in sharepoint using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, active-directory

I need to get an user info from AD into a list that I am filling in using javascript. For some, I use SP services, but now I need to get an address  (street, city, postal code), telephone number and email of a currently signed in user. I can get phone number and email from SP service function SPGetCurrentUser but how about that address? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use Rest API and get the desired properties:

```
$.ajax({

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        try {
            //Get properties from user profile Json response  
            var properties = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results;
            accountName = GetPropertyVal(properties, "AccountName");
            Location = GetPropertyVal(properties, "SPS-Location");
            SIP = GetPropertyVal(properties, "SPS-sipAddress");

            $("[title='CurrentUser']").val(accountName);



        } catch (err2) {

        }
    },
    error: function (jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {

    }
});


 function GetPropertyVal(properties, key) {
var value = "";
for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    if (properties[i].Key == key) {
        value = properties[i].Value;
        break;
    }
}
return value;
 }
```